# Convert MySQL query to Active Record in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this mysql query and I am very new to CodeIgniter. How can I convert this mysql query into CodeIgniter's Active Record?

```
SELECT chp_destination, cde_name, chp_year, chp_from, chp_to, chp_budget_price_high, 
chp_medium_price_high, chp_luxury_price_high, chp_budget_price_low, chp_medium_price_low, chp_luxury_price_low, chp_timestamp, chp_comment , MAX( chp_timestamp ) AS last_updated, MAX( chp_id )
FROM crm_hotel_price
LEFT JOIN crm_destinations ON cde_id = chp_destination
GROUP BY chp_destination, chp_year
ORDER BY chp_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [(Reference)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
$this->db->select('chp_destination, cde_name, chp_year, chp_from, chp_to, chp_budget_price_high, chp_medium_price_high, chp_luxury_price_high, chp_budget_price_low, chp_medium_price_low, chp_luxury_price_low, chp_timestamp, chp_comment, MAX(chp_timestamp) AS last_updated, MAX(chp_id)', FALSE);
$this->db->join('crm_destinations', 'cde_id = chp_destination', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('chp_destination, chp_year');
$this->db->order_by('chp_id');
$qry = $this->db->get('crm_hotel_price');
$res = $qry->result(); // or $qry->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$rs = $this->db->select('chp_destination, cde_name, chp_year, chp_from, chp_to, chp_budget_price_high, chp_medium_price_high, chp_luxury_price_high, chp_budget_price_low, chp_medium_price_low, chp_luxury_price_low, chp_timestamp, chp_comment , MAX( chp_timestamp ) AS last_updated, MAX( chp_id )', false)
      ->from('crm_hotel_price')
      ->join('crm_destinations', 'cde_id = chp_destination', 'LEFT')
      ->group_by(array('chp_destination', 'chp_year'))
      ->order_by('chp_id')
      ->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: you can write table name in get() also. Then you dont need to write from().

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
 > $this->db->select('chp_destination, cde_name, chp_year, chp_from, chp_to, chp_budget_price_high,
```

chp_medium_price_high, chp_luxury_price_high, chp_budget_price_low, chp_medium_price_low, chp_luxury_price_low, chp_timestamp, chp_comment , MAX( chp_timestamp ) AS last_updated, MAX( chp_id )');

> $this->db->from('crm_hotel_price');
>   $this->db->join('crm_destinations','cde_id = chp_destination','LEFT'); // join with another table
>   $this->db->group_by('chp_destination,chp_year'); // for grouping of field
>   $this->db->order_by("chp_id", "asc"); // for sorting field value
>   $query = $this->db->get();
>           return $query->result_array(); // It will return result
>   and use this line to view whole SQL query.
>    **echo $this->db->last_query();**